# PHP and Regex - optional part

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem involving PHP and regex.

I have some files and need to capture some of the names. But there's one part that are not in all.

Example files: 
D.SAE.IND.001.TME.BR.SER.20120729
D.SUI.IND.003.TMC.GER.TOT.201206 
D.SAE.LIS.008.AGE.APS.SER.45D.20120713

Note that the last file has a part ("45D") that is optional.
 I need to get every group. I was using the following regex:
 `preg_match('/D\.(?P<font>[\w]*)\.(?P<tipo>[\w]*)\.(?P<numberLevel>[\d]*)\.(?P<indicator>[\w]*)\.(?P<nameLevel>[\w]*)\.(?P<group>[\w]*)\.(?P<id>[\d]*)/i', $arrInput , $result);`

The problem is that optional part (eg the latest file - "45D").
 I need this result:
D.SAE.IND.001.TME.BR.SER.20120729
$result['fonte'] = 'SAE'
$result['tipo'] = 'IND'
$result['numberLevel'] = '001'
$result['indicator'] = 'TME'
$result['nameLevel'] = 'BR'
$result['group'] = 'SER'
$result['op'] = ''
$result['id'] = '20120729'

D.SAE.LIS.008.AGE.APS.SER.45D.20120713
$result['fonte'] = 'SAE'
$result['tipo'] = 'LIS'
$result['numberLevel'] = '008'
$result['indicator'] = 'AGE'
$result['nameLevel'] = 'APS'
$result['group'] = 'SER'
$result['op'] = '45D'
$result['id'] = '20120713'

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
/D\.(?P<font>[\w]*)\.(?P<tipo>[\w]*)\.(?P<numberLevel>[\d]*)\.(?P<indicator>[\w]*)\.(?P<nameLevel>[\w]*)\.(?P<group>[\w]*)\.(?:(?P<op>.*)\.)?(?P<id>[\d]*)/i
```

The key is adding:

```
(?:(?P<op>.*)\.)?
```

Before the `id` group.

**Edit**: Added the `?:` to make the grouping non-capturing.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just use `explode('.', $string)`?

You can count the array to see the number of entries.  If it's 7, you know you are missing the optional string.

Comment: +1 I **love** switching from a regex to explode!  Two birds with one stone :)

Comment: thanks. It's a great idea. But, only for curiosity: is possible with regex?

Comment: @NakaBr probably..  If you'd like to do it as an exercise you can try.  Check out the other answer too!